How can I customize Azure AD B2C Email MFA template?
I have an existing Azure AD B2C "Sign in" user flow that has MFA enabled. I was able to customize the page layouts for all the pages such as Sign in page, Multifactor authentication page using email, etc.
But how do I customize the look of the Azure AD B2C MFA email template?
Thanks!
I have tried to search around but it seems that we are able to integrate SendGrid and MailJet to customize the look of the email, but I just wish to customize the look of the email while utilizing the default user flow "Sign in" type from Azure AD B2C and perhaps not utilizing any external services or parties.

The only thing you can do is via branding.
"The banner logo appears in the verification emails sent to your users when they initiate a sign-up user flow"
Not sure if this applies to MFA email?

Thanks @rbrayb, othewise, is there any other way you could recommend? Would it be possible by doing custom policy?

Not directly - you could call SendGrid from the custom policy, but that's all.

@rbryab, thanks for that. But if we utilize SendGrid and implementing the custom policy, will we still be able to utilize the default user flows Azure provides for signin?

Yes - wrote this up - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/mix-and-match-with-user-flows-and-custom-policies-in-azure-ad-b2c-f54a867b327d

@rbryab, thanks for this, but as I was reading in Microsoft's FAQ page, is it possible to change just the banner background color and footer logo from the default Azure AD B2C MFA email verification template? Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga, this was asked: "How do I customize verification emails (the content and the "From:" field) sent by Azure AD B2C?"
